# How do you only print first 4 strings inside a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, file, external

I have a piece of code that sorts a list of data in an external file and i need to print the first 4 lines that are inside that file.

I have tried searching everywhere with no success.

```
f=open('SortWin.txt', 'r')
if f.mode == 'r':
winList = f.read()
print('\nHere are the Top 4 Players\n[Score][Name]')
#Need to change winList to only the first 4 names here
print(winList)
f.close()
```

My external file 'SortWin.txt' looks like this:

```
11 Tom
16 Tom
18 Ben
20 Tom
21 Ben
23 Tom
36 Tom
42 Tom
45 Tom
46 Tom
98 Ben
99 Tom
```

The current output is:

```
11 Tom
16 Tom
18 Ben
20 Tom
21 Ben
23 Tom
36 Tom
42 Tom
45 Tom
46 Tom
98 Ben
99 Tom
```

I need this to be the output:

```
11 Tom
16 Tom
18 Ben
20 Tom
21 Ben
```

Thanks

Comment: `print(winList.split("\n")[:4])` ? As a side note your expected output contains 5 elements :)

Comment: @CristiFati you have 20k points and still don't follow the guidelines of community ? Comments are not for answering https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment

Comment: @MatheusGomes: I am very aware of the guidelines. But I didn't have enough details to post an answer (with good chances to be correct), because I didn't know how the file is formatted (before the question edit it looked totally different). So I asked for details (you can see it that way too), by blindly attempting different alternative, until finding the right one.

Comment: @MatheusGomes: Good call! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now you just have to split and slice the list, just like that:

```
#Get 4 elements, splitting for each line
print( '\n'.join(winList.split('\n')[:4]) )
```

Comment: Thanks that does work but it outputs ['11 Tom', '15 Tom', '20 Ben', '20 Tom'] is there any way it can get rid of the square brackets, commas, and apostrophes?

Comment: @ThomasDraper just use the string "join" method. I edited my answer according to this.